# Local folders not created during setup

Tags: node, tezos-client, docker, setup

I'm very new to Tezos and Docker. I've been following the instructions here: https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html to download and setup babylonnet. Took a while to figure out I had to run `./babylonnet.sh shell` to run any of the commands, but I got passed that, setup my identity and started the bootstrap.

Its running, and the bootstrapping eventually reported it was up to date, but none of the local folders seem to exist. I get "no such file or directory" for:

- $HOME/.tezos-client
- /var/run/tezos/client
- /var/run/tezos/node/data
- etc.

I can't find my identity.json or verify anything on my system, it all seems to be inside docker and I don't know how to access it. I ran `inspect` on `babylonnet_node_1` and it does have mounts listed, but the destinations don't exist on my side:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "babylonnet_client_data",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/babylonnet_client_data/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/run/tezos/client",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "babylonnet_node_data",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/babylonnet_node_data/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/run/tezos/node",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
```

Is there something i'm missing? is there a set of steps I needed to do first?

I'm on a Mac, running 10.15.2 Catalina